# Convert an Rows or Columns to a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-manipulation

I know I can extract columns like this:

```
  userData1.select(userData1("job"))
```

But what if I already have a column, or an array of columns, how do I get a dataframe out of it? What has worked for me so far is:

```
  userData1.select(userData1("id"), userData1("age"))
```

This is a bit verbose and ugly compared to what you can do in R:

```
userData1[, c("id", "age")]
```

And what about rows? For example:

```
  userData1.head(5)
```

How do you convert this into a new dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple columns you can use varargs syntax:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df: DataFrame = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "x", 2.0), (2, "y", 3.0), (3, "z", 4.0)
)).toDF("foo", "bar", "baz")


// or df.select(Seq("foo", "baz") map col: _*)
val fooAndBaz: DataFrame = df.select(Seq($"foo", $"baz"): _*)
fooAndBaz.show

// +---+---+
// |foo|baz|
// +---+---+
// |  1|2.0|
// |  2|3.0|
// |  3|4.0|
// +---+---+
```

PySpark equivalent is arguments unpacking:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "x", 2.0), (2, "y", 3.0), (3, "z", 4.0)],
    ("foo", "bar", "baz"))

df.select(*["foo", "baz"]).show()

## +---+---+
## |foo|baz|
## +---+---+
## |  1|2.0|
## |  2|3.0|
## |  3|4.0|
## +---+---+
```

To limit number of rows without collecting you can use limit method:

```
val firstTwo: DataFrame = df.limit(2)
firstTwo.show

//  +---+---+---+
//  |foo|bar|baz|
//  +---+---+---+
//  |  1|  x|2.0|
//  |  2|  y|3.0|
//  +---+---+---+
```

which is equivalent to SQL `LIMIT` clause:

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM df LIMIT 2").show

//  +---+---+---+
//  |foo|bar|baz|
//  +---+---+---+
//  |  1|  x|2.0|
//  |  2|  y|3.0|
//  +---+---+---+
```